# Where are the user account icons/pictures stored in Windows XP? (The ones that are displayed on the non-classic logon/welcome screen.)

Tags: windows-xp

Where are the user account icons/pictures stored in Windows XP?

(The ones that are displayed on the non-classic logon screen and the start menu.)

Answer (score 3):

> C:\Document and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\User
>   Account Pictures\

Answer (score 1):

c:\Windows\system32\msgina.dll, winlogon.exe and logonui.exe contain these resources as bitmaps.
reshack can be used to look at them and if you are adventurous modify them.

You will need to first rename msgina.dll and logonui.exe to something like msgina.old, and then copy in the modified files.